# Как достать дату из названия файла?

Tags: bash

Мне с помощью bash скрипта нужно удалять файлы, если они старше чем две недели. Вот пример названия файла bliznetsy_17-07-2023__03-01.dump. Дата создания файла вшита в название (в данном случае дата создания 17.07.2023). Как мне из названия доставать дату создания файла, так что бы скрипт корректно воспринимал эту дату?

Папка с файлами находится на виртуальной машине Linux.

Пробовал вот так, но падает с ошибкой что дата некорректна

```html
#!/bin/bash

backup_folder="/dev/backupsTest"  

# Рассчитываем текущую дату и дату 2 недели назад
current_date=$(date +%s)
two_weeks_ago=$(date -d "2 weeks ago" +%s)

# Перебираем файлы в папке с бэкапами
for file in "$backup_folder"/*; do
  # Получаем дату файла из его имени
  filename=$(basename "$file")
  date_part=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d'_' -f2)
  file_date=$(date -d "${date_part//__/ }" +%s)

  # Проверяем, старше ли файл двух недель и не является ли датой 5, 15 или 25 числа
  if [[ $file_date -lt $two_weeks_ago ]] && ! [[ "${date_part:0:2}" =~ ^(05|15|25)$ ]]; then
    # Удаляем файл
    rm "$file"
    echo "Удален файл: $file"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Вам надо переставить элементы даты в `date_part`. Сейчас у вас там что-то вроде `17-07-2023`, а правильная дата это `2023-07-17`

Comment: Можно, например так -- `file_date=$(date -d \`echo $date_part  | tr -- '-' ' ' | (read d m y; echo "${y}-${m}-${d}")\` +%s)`

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял что нужно

```
#Получаем день, месяц, год из переменной filename
IFS='-' read day mm yyyy < <(grep -oP '(?<=_)([0-9]{2}-){2}[0-9]{4}(?=_)' <<< "${filename}")

#Приводим дату к виду, который станет валидным для date текущий локали, получаем секунды
file_date=$(date -d "${yyyy}-${mm}-${day}" +%s)
```

Если файл имеет имя `bliznetsy_17-07-2023__03-01.dump`, то в переменную `file_date` будет записано значение `1689541200`

---

UPD:
Если можно использовать `awk`, то можно выбрать нужные столбцы используя несколько разделителей:

```
#filename="bliznetsy_17-08-2023__03-01.dump"
file_date=$(date -d `awk -F'[-_]' 'OFS="-" {print $4,$3,$2}' <<< "${filename}"` %s)
#file_date=1692219600
```

Важно! Количество нижних подчеркиваний и тире до даты должно быть одинаковым

Answer (score 1):

`find` все сделает за вас:

```
find /dev/backupsTest -type f -mtime +14 -delete
```